# JSP JPA Form: how to insert value in a path variable

Tags: forms, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

I have the following code snippet in a jsp file:

```
<hr>
<form:form commandName="newTicketSale" id="reg" action="transactionResult.htm">
    <h3>Buy Movie Tickets:</h3>
    <form:label path="movieName">Movie Name:</form:label>
    <form:input path="movieName" />
    <form:errors class="invalid" path="movieName" />
    <form:label path="ticketPrice">Ticket Price:</form:label>
    <form:input path="ticketPrice" />
    <form:errors class="invalid" path="ticketPrice" />
     <input type="submit"> <br><br>
</form:form>
```

I am using JPA tags in this jsp. Now, in the commandName "newTicketSale" there is another parameter called userId. In the jsp file itself I need to insert value ${name} in userId, so that in the Controller file when I am doing

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("newTicketSale") MovieTicket newTicket
```

I can retrieve the value ${name} when I am doing newTicket.getUserId().

I don't know how to do this. Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `modelattribute` tag in `form:form` like below

```
form:form method="post" action="example.html" modelAttribute="newTicketSale"
```

so that the value entered in the form will be retrieved using `newTicket.getters`